# Image disappears when resizing the canvas

Tags: java, image, canvas, processing

I'm launching this demo code from lectures

```
package demos;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class MyPApplet extends PApplet{
    PImage img;

    public void setup() {
        //Add setup code for MyPApplet
        size(600,600);  //set canvas size>>changed to size(700,800)
        background(255);            //set canvas color
        stroke(0);              //set pen color
        img = loadImage("palmTrees.jpg", "jpg");
        img.resize(0, height);          //resize loaded image to full height of canvas
        image(img, 0, 0);           //display image 
    }

    public void draw() {
        //Add drawing code for MyPApplet
        int[] color = sunColorSec(second());        //calculate color code for sun
        fill(color[0],color[1],color[2]);   //set sun color
        ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/4,height/5); //draw sun
    }


    /** Return the RGB color of the sun at this number of seconds in the minute */
    public int[] sunColorSec(float seconds)
    {
        int[] rgb = new int[3];
        // Scale the brightness of the yellow based on the seconds.  0 seconds 
        // is black.  30 seconds is bright yellow.
        float diffFrom30 = Math.abs(30-seconds);

        float ratio = diffFrom30/30;
        rgb[0] = (int)(255*ratio);
        rgb[1] = (int)(255*ratio);
        rgb[2] = 0;

        //System.out.println("R" + rgb[0] + " G" + rgb[1] + " B" + rgb[2]);
        return rgb;
    }   

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //Add main method for running as application
        PApplet.main(new String[] {"--present", "MyPApplet"});
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to change the size of my canvas to more than (600,600), then the background image disappears. Here is what I'm talking about:
and here is a copy of the image i 'm working on https://www.mediafire.com/?dnpghfefeo7rl5o

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: @ochi (and others: ) Note that this question is about https://processing.org - rules are a bit different there...

Comment: @Marco13   thanks for your edit ,things look better now :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't test this right now (you seem to use an old version of processing, because in versions >3.0, `PApplet` does no longer extend `Applet`, and some other things changed there as well). But to understand this better: Does the image disappear when you change the size *in the code*, or only when you *resize* the window with the mouse?

Comment: it disappears when i change the size in my code ,   people told me that things has changed in the new version , but i have to follow up with my instructors

Comment: Your code works fine for me using Processing 2.2.1. Can you please provide the exact code you're running for your "after" scenario? Can you also please provide us with a copy of the image you're using?

Comment: here is  a copy of the image [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?dnpghfefeo7rl5o)  
 i haven't change the code for much ,  in the setup method i have changed the line  size(600,600);  to be size(700,800);

Comment: That image and that size work fine for me on Windows 10 using Processing 2.2.1. What exact version of Processing are you using? (btw you might want to put @KevinWorkman at the beginning of your reply so I get a notification for it, otherwise I won't see it!)

Comment: @KevinWorkman  no, i'm using an older version , v2.0 and i'm running on windows 7

Comment: @KareemEmad The first thing I would try if I were you is upgrading to version 2.2.1.

Comment: @KevinWorkman yes , i think the problem is  with the old version as it work on yours and not   on mine , thanks kevin

Comment: @KareemEmad You'd be best off upgrading to the newest version of Processing (Processing 3), but your code contains a few things that work differently between Processing 2 and Processing 3, so at the very least you should upgrade to a newer version of Processing 2. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @KevinWorkman ok, i will try this , but how do i upgrade  to a newer version?

Comment: @KareemEmad Just go to Processing's website and then to the download section. Both Processing 3 and Processing 2.2.1 are available there. Unzip that folder, then look for `core.jar`. Add that to your classpath.

Comment: @KevinWorkman great! , i will try this out ,and let you know the results .. thanks kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not displaying the image in your `draw` method. Instead, you are only displaying it once, in `setup`. When you resize the canvas, then the window will be cleared and `draw` will be called. *There* you should paint the image:

```
public void draw() {

    image(img, 0, 0);  // <---- Add this here!

    //Add drawing code for MyPApplet
    ...
...
```